# Looking for Office365 REST endpoint to share a site with an external user

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, external-users

I want to add a (new) external user to an Office365 Sharepoint site

This article: https://dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices-detail/1870
has this piece of code:

```
SharingResult result = ctx.Web.ShareSite("someone@example.com", ExternalSharingSiteOption.Edit,true, "Here's a site shared for you.");
```

Especially this remark gives me hope:

> Notice - This capability is also available with RESTful interfaces.

I know how to get lists etc... using REST (and OAuth) but I cannot find the endpoint and payload (JSON) to send to this endpoint to achieve my goal.

=== update ====

When I post JSON to this endpoint

```
https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/*****/_api/SP.Web.ShareObject
```

JSON

```
{
"url":"https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/*****/",
"peoplePickerInput":"external user @ otherorg.com",
"sendEmail":"true",
"emailSubject":"Hello World"
}
```

I get this error:

> "ErrorMessage": "SPWeb.ShareObjectInternal: no resolved users. >ShareByEmailEnabled: False, CanPickerAcceptAnyEmail: False

Does this mean a misconfiguration in SharePoint or should I provide my new external user in a different way ?

Comment: @vesa-juvonen I hope you can point me in the right direction ?

Comment: This SO question might help you a bit. Please check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162921/document-sharing-with-sp-web-shareobject-rest-api-return-200-response-with-error